# UITableView with page-enable cells (Cells that Snap into Place)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to make my cells snap into place, where the height of my cells is `UITableViewCell height = self.view.frame.size.height - 80`

I'm using this code to snap them. This works when scrolling upward, but when I scroll downward I run into a problem where if I completely drag the next cell onto the screen, it will snap back to the current cell, even if I scroll so far that only a little bit of the current cell is still showing. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    NSIndexPath *pathForTargetTopCell = [self.purchasesTableview indexPathForRowAtPoint:CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.purchasesTableview.bounds), targetContentOffset->y)];
    targetContentOffset->y = [self.purchasesTableview rectForRowAtIndexPath:pathForTargetTopCell].origin.y;
}
```

A sample `UITableViewCell` from my `UITableView`

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any code to make your screen-sized cells snap into place, you can do it by selecting the "Paging Enabled" check box in IB for the table view.